# Creating responsive design in iOS - Am I doing it correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I do not have to much experience working with responsive design in iOS apps.

I have been writing custom views using the proportions of a photoshop image and then typing it out in a custom UIView class as seen here is an example from a view I created:

```
    let contentX = bounds.width * 0.05
    let contentWidth = bounds.width * 0.9
    let titleY = bounds.height * 0.1037
    let titleHeight = bounds.height * 0.35556
    let buttonY = titleY + titleHeight + (bounds.height * 0.126)
    let buttonHeight = bounds.height * 0.31111
    let backWidth = contentWidth * 0.3
    let problemsX = (contentWidth * 0.35) + contentX
    let problemsWidth = contentWidth * 0.65
```

In order to calculate these proportions I would go into Photoshop and find the x,y coordinates and the width and height then I would divide the x and width by the total width of the view and the y and height by the height of the view. This gives me a decimal number that I can use to find the size and origin of the UIElement no matter the dimensions of the view.

This is A LOT OF TEDIOUS WORK, am I doing this properly?

I feel as if this is bordering on a subjective question so please constrain the answers to these constraints, do not give me your personal subjective opinions please only reference notable style guides or techniques. Are there software alternatives?

Comment: You should have a look at Auto Layout, here's [Apple's Introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I use autolayout for storyboard but these are for my custom views

Comment: Are you not using Auto Layout for your custom views as well then? Have you looked into creating `NSLayoutConstraint`s programatically?

Comment: No I have not I will do that, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AutoLayout, that's what it's for.

- See Apple's [AutoLayout Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).
- There is also a bunch of videos from WWDC sessions for previous years, like session 202 of WWDC 2012 and such.

> Note: You are talking about doing "Responsive Design", not "Reactive Design".
>   ("Responsive Design" = "make it so that the UI adapts to the screen size". "Reactive" is another, totally different concept related to how to design the workflow of your data in your app, like by using ReactiveCocoa and such). Maybe you should edit your question and title to make it clearer ;-)